# On discretization in QFT and second quantization

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, field-theory, discrete, lattice-model

Some time ago i saw in a QFT lecture series by the IFT UNESP that in QFT we need to discretize space by dividing it into tiny boxes of an arbitrary Volume $ \Delta V $ and then define canonical position and momentum as

$ x_i(t) = \phi(\vec{x_i}, t) \sqrt{\Delta V} $

$ p_i(t) = \pi(\vec{x_i}, t) \sqrt{\Delta V} $

Where $ \pi $ is the canonical momentum of $ \phi $

But aren't $ \phi $ and $ \pi $ supposed to be field functions? Doesn't this mean they are like the quantum wavefunction of quantum mechanics which assigns to any point in spacetime a probability of finding the particle they describe with a concrete position/momentum value? Why (and how) we define coordinates (a feature of spacetime) in terms of probability of finding a particle there (a feature of matter itself)?

And why is the normalization $ \Delta V $ chosen? What physical meaning does it have ?

Also, when defining the states of the theory in the video we have

$ \hat{a}_k \rightarrow \sqrt{V(2\pi)^3} \hat{\alpha}_k $

$ \hat{a}^{\dagger}_k \rightarrow \sqrt{V(2\pi)^3} \hat{\alpha}^{\dagger}_k $

Where the alphas are "discretized" versions of the ladder operators
What does he mean by discretized ladder operators? And again, why is the normalization what it is?

This brings me to my second question

In the theory the position operators and eigenstates doesn't exist, instead the position eigenstate is replaced by $ \phi(x) | \Omega > $ again what sense does it make to define the position in terms of matter fields? Why the position operator and its states doesnt exist?

And also what is the difference between $ \tilde{\phi} (p) $ the momentum space representation of $ \phi $ and $ \pi (x, t) $ the momentum conjugate of the position field function?

or TLDR; what are $ \phi(x) $, $ \pi (x, t) $, $ \tilde{\phi}(p, t) $ and $ \tilde{\pi}(p, t) $ exactly? What is their phisycal meaning?

Comment: Link to lecture? Which minute?